# How to UPDATE data in MySQL after a scheduled time

Tags: mysql, database

I am new to SQL and I want to update the Amount in the amount field. For example in every month in 3 months I want to add 100 to THE 500 in the amount field in the database. And when the 3rd month comes It will automatically transfer the data to another table

This is the the code I have done so far, but its not working

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
 DO
  UPDATE message
  SET amount*3
  WHERE date = NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the update command into:
   UPDATE Message
   SET amount = amount + 100
   WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) >=value

Comment: In this part, can I make it to % operator? because is my system I need to add 3% of the amount every month

Comment: % operator in sql returns a remainder of a division between two operands. But you can write it like this : SET amount = amount + (amount*0.03)

Comment: what type of date shoud i use? date or datetime? And what is the value for?

Comment: Here you can find more info about DATEDIFF function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx . In my example,  date should be the same type returned by the curdate function (datetime type) and value stands for the difference between the dates (in you case, 3 months)